# How to update multiple elements in a MooTools Request.HTML call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, mootools, xmlhttprequest

Using MooTools Request.HTML, I have my Request call working perfectly, updating my page element by using something like:

```
onComplete: function() {
    var response = this.response.text;
    $('content').set("html", response); 
}
```

However, I'd like to be able to have a response have multiple elements that are updated by ID and I can't for the life of me get this working correctly.  For instance, if my response is:

```
<response>
    <div id="header"><h1>My Title</h1></div>
    <div id="content"><h2>Content</h2><p>This is my content</p></div>
    <div id="footer"><p>Special footer for this page</p></div>
</response>
```

I would like the code to loop through the child elements of <response>, grab the id, match that id to an element in the page, and replace the element innerHTML of the page with the element innerHTML from the response.  It didn't seem to be that hard but I just can't seem to get this working.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can walk the returned elements form Request.HTML like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/NF2jz/1139/

```
new Request.HTML({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        html: data,
        delay: 1
    },
    method: 'post',
    onComplete: function() {
        // first, only get elements that have an id and are divs
        // this may be slow as it looks for ALL els returned, depends on your
        // fragment 
        var filtered = this.response.elements.filter(function(el) {
            return el.get("id") && el.get("tag") == "div";
        });

        // This wil be even faster, working with your response fragment 
        // where your els are children of the first node:
        // get div els where id is set via Slick
        var filtered = this.response.tree[0].getElements("div[id]");

        filtered.each(function(el) {
            // get the id
            var id = el.get("id");
            // remove the id from the element so dom selector works correctly
            el.set("id", null);

            // look for dom element that matches
            var target = document.id(id);

            // if found, update html
            if (target)
                target.set("html", el.get("html"));

        });
    }
}).send();
```

as Tim Weink from mootools-core likes to point out, I have a nasty habit of using undocumented mootools features that fall outside of the public API, such as accessing `this.response` directly where I should use the named arguments instead. Keep it in mind and look at the documentation on which argument will match `this.response.elements` or `this.response.tree` - in the **unlikely** event that mootools change their API and make that unavailable.

Comment: ALTHOUGH: as Itay suggested, you'd be far better off going to a JSON solution to supply the fragments for this.

Comment: +1 - you did answer my question so I will give the accepted answer to you. However, even as you state, I think I may ultimately go with Itay's JSON solution.  But I will definitely keep this code in my toolbox because I'm sure I'll need it.

Comment: good call - in which case - `responseJSON.data.each(function(el) { var domel = $(el.id); if (domel) { domel.set("html", el.html); }  // exists });`

Comment: I know this is old, but `onComplete` should be `onSuccess` ... this is an error I see all-too-often.

Comment: ... and maybe that's why you don't like using `function(tree, elements, html, js)` ... because `onComplete` does not have that signature.

Comment: no. i don't like using `onSuccess` because it's shit. the subclassing of Request do particular things that do not translate to a successful request. for example, `onSuccess` on Request.JSON means getting a response AND making an object. you send 204 (no content) and it fires `onFailure`. `onComplete` lets you decide for yourself if everything works. then there is isSuccess and so on... Request is now a little old :(

Answer (score 1):

```
onSuccess:function(responseJSON, responseText)
{
    var data_length = responseJSON.data.length;
    for(var i=0;i<data_length;i++){
         $(responseJSON.data[i].id).set('html',responseJSON.data[i].html);
    }
}
```

The JSON reposnse from server

```
{data: [
        {id:"header",html:"<h1>My title</h1>"},
        {id:"content",html:"<h2>Content</h2><p>This is my content</p>"},
        ....  
       ]  
}
```

There are some short cutts you can do, but this shows the logic.

Comment: +1 - I do like this. But I was hoping for a solution that can use the response.text.  I employ some templating that either assembles a full page for regular requests or just returns the xhtml (including the containing element like <div id="content" /> for each section (like content, header, etc) for ajax requests.  If I go this route, I'd need to parse that xhtml; grabbing the id and extracting the innerHTML and converting to JSON in PHP.  I will if that's my only choice, but I'd rather not.

Comment: if this is XHTML you can use simple_xml, but, aren't you generating it all on the server?
Or even more, do you not use a MVC approach?

Comment: Yes, I am using MVC and I would use simple_xml to parse.  I think my biggest issue is that each of my templates have the containing element (<div id="content"><div><p>....</div>). If they just contained the innerHTML, I could easily employ your method here with about 2 lines of code.  I may change that aspect of my templates because this is a much cleaner approach.  I just have about 50 templates (but soon to grow) right now that I would need to change.